# Get the location of PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow

in my app I show a popup using [popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View)). How can I get the x,y of this popupWindow?

Comment: pest your code portion here .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

```
int[] location = new int[2];    
popupWindow.getContentView(). getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Rect rc = new Rect();
View.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rc);
int[] xy = new int[2];
View.getLocationInWindow(xy);
rc.offset(xy[0], xy[1]);
```

now you have

```
 inx x = rc.left, y = rc.top;
```